# How to Change Swiper pagination color in Flutter?

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter-layout, swiper.js

I am using Swiper as a slider in Flutter Activity i want to change Swiper dot indicator color from Blue(default) to custom, but i am unable to find the way how to change indicator color and also i want to change the location of indicator inside the container.
[image]

Comment: Do you have a code example to see what package and the parameters are you using

Comment: Container(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 170,
                child: Swiper(
                  itemCount: 5,
                  viewportFraction: 0.8,
                  scale: 0.9,
                  itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 165,
                      child: function(Tteam1[i], Tteam2[i], Turl1[i], Turl2[i],Tdate1[i],Tloc[i]), ); },  ,),),),

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i have found the solution of this problem by Adding the following code inside the Swiper widget.

```
 pagination: new SwiperPagination(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                builder: new DotSwiperPaginationBuilder(
                    color: Colors.grey, activeColor: Color(0xff38547C)),
              ),
              control: new SwiperControl(
                color: Color(0xff38547C),
              ),
```

After adding this code the output is like this:
[image]